# Are there Size limits for flutter json.decode?

Tags: json, flutter, decode

I have a dictionary file with 200,000 items in it.
I have a Dictionary Model which matches the SQLite db and the proper methods.

If I try to parse the whole file, it seems to hang.  If I do 8000 items, it seems to do it quite quickly.  Is there a size limit, or is just because there might be some corrupted data somewhere?  This json was exported from the sqlite db as json pretty, so I would imagine it was done correctly.  It also works fine with the first 8000 items.

```
String peuJson = await getPeuJson();
    List<Dictionary> dicts = (json.decode(peuJson) as List)
        .map((i) => Dictionary.fromJson(i))
        .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is similar to other data formats like XML - if you need to transmit more data, you just send more data. There's no inherent size limitation to the JSON request. Any limitation would be set by the server parsing the request.

Comment: well .. i think maybe it might just be that dart is incredibly slow.  I made a for loop for 200,000 times and built a random csv string (no writing or parsing).  It takes a few seconds per thousand.  It was so slow, I had to put debug statements per 1000.  I did not finish the code.. no need.  If you have 200,000 then that is 600 seconds or 10 minutes.  I run real-world processing code in js node, and I built a real 18mb file in a few seconds total (same computer).  I'm totally shocked at what is going on.
I think there was some limit of 80,000 in the example of my OP.

Comment: Example... 

String myString = "";
    // make 200k records
    for (int x = 0; x < 200000; x++) {
      myString += "$x, another variable$x, 8\n";
      if (x % 1000 == 1) {
        debugPrint("$x");
      }
    }